# jQuery + Fancybox stops working after click on a certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this piece of code before  the /body tag:

```
 //// Opens links in FancyBox (loads only .entry-content)

    jQuery('.evcal_list_a, #events-mobile .evcal_list_a').fancybox({
    'width': '95%',
    'height': '95%',
    'type': 'ajax',
    'transitionOut': 'elastic',
    'transitionIn': 'elastic',
     'ajax': {
        dataFilter: function(data) {
            return jQuery(data).find('.entry-content')[0];
        }         
    }
});
```

[As you can see here](http://vps12217.inmotionhosting.com/~tukano5/clients/thelexington.co.uk/#events)

if you try to click on any events tiles they will open correctly in a fancybox, though if you click on the next (>) or previous (<) month arrow, it loads the events for that month and the fancybox will not open anymore taking the user to the actual link.

[image]

How can I have this jQuery script reload every time the user navigates to a different month?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your jquery function did that work once the page was loaded.

while changing months jquery wasn't executed. and hence no fancybox.

solution : add a trigger to your jquery for month changes too.

Comment: thank you very much for your help Nirpendra, do you have any suggestions about how to amend my function?

Comment: I've been able to make this work by wrapping my function into this: `jQuery('body').on('mouseover', '.evcal_list_a', function() { //function here });  ` So this way I'm sure the function will always load before the user clicks. Not sure it's the best way to do it but it works well so far. Thank you

Comment: @Pelly try with div class=eventon_events_list. I think triggering it with each single element mouseover is overkill. and sorry for not replying on how to trigger and the reason was people in here don't try anything themselves. it's nice that u got help from my hints. +1up

Comment: You're right! we can trigger the function once by hovering the whole container. Thank you for pointing that out, it worked! - Regarding the reason why you didn't answer: I totally agree with you. I see many people just pasting here what they need and expecting the others to do it for them. I always try for days before asking for help as I don't like bothering people, but unfortunately I still have a lot to learn with jQuery so I needed some help. Thanks for giving me the right terminology that helped me make my google search succesful. Have a nice day!